# automount vmware shared folder in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, vmware, fstab, automount

I have shared by drive D: from my Windows 10 host to my Ubuntu 14.04 guest in VMware. Ubuntu successfully mounts this share into */mnt/hgfs/D*.

However I would like to automount it to /D on startup.

Manually mounting it to D in terminal with *sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/D /D* works fine in Ubuntu 14.04.

Automounting it by adding the entry *.host:/D /D vmhgfs defaults 0 0* in /etc/fstab has worked fine in Ubuntu 12.04, but after updating to 14.04 it results in Ubuntu prompting the following error on startup:
"An error occurred while mounting /D. Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery".
When pressing 'S', Ubuntu finishes booting, but /D is empty.

How can I automount my VMware shares in Ubuntu 14.04?